# PayPal Adaptive Payments is automatically refunding orders

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

On some occasions our customers are reporting that their payments from their customers are being automatically refunded.

We've noticed that this seems to be increasing over time.

When the refund occurs sometimes the users are presented with an error message like "Sorry your payment could not be completed at this time, please try again later".

We are using an adaptive payment setup with multiple receivers (2 to be exact).

Has anyone had this issue, is it an integration issue, or any work arounds?

Also we're using the PHP sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Typically this occurs when the some of the recipients are not able to receive funds.

Some scenarios I'm aware of:

- A receiver account has an issue or restriction that prevents it from receiving any PayPal payments at all.
- Primary receiver of the chained payment is a Mexican PayPal account, which due to local regulations cannot hold or use a balance to forward funds to the secondary receiver, and so the adaptive payment will always be reversed (no workaround, chained payments cannot be used to an MX primary)
- A chained secondary receiver is in one of certain Caribbean and smaller island countries that requires some kind of auto-sweep withdrawal method

If your user isn't able to determine what's wrong by logging into their account and reviewing messages there, they'll need to contact PayPal's support to ask about the reversals.  It could be one of the reasons above or some other account issue

But basically these are account or country issues that cause an error with part of the payment, not a programming issue.

And by default, Adaptive Payments have reverseAllPaymentsOnError::yes. This is a payment creation setting, and likely something you want to keep as-is

---

Adaptive is a legacy product and support ended for new integrations in Dec of 2017, so you will want to see if you can become a PayPal partner and move to something new like the Commerce Platform, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/commerce-platform/onboarding/partner-onboarding/